# XML Auto-complete for DOCTYPE Declaration and others

Tags: xml, autocomplete, declaration

I am learning XML, XPath and so on. I am using the Atom editor with some plugins for XML.
Could someone, please, tell me, how add the long XHTML DOCTYPE declaratioin automatically with auto-complete to the XML document? I tried different possibilities like tab and enter after writing "!", but all failed. Does someone know a site with all auto-complete commands?

Thank you very much. Have a great day. Stay safe.

Martina